# Capture word from regex match

Tags: regex, perl

I am working on a regex in perl, which identifies what I want it to: word final g (but not following an 'n') or k (but not following an 'r') that precedes word-initial g (but not l or r), word-initial k, or word-initial c (but not c preceding i, e, y, or h):

`(((?<!n)g)|(?<!r)k)\s(g(?!l|r)|k|c(?!i|e|y|h));`

However, I want it to capture the word that has the g or k at the end of it, so I tried something like this:
`(^|\s.*(((?<!n)g)|(?<!r)k))\s(g(?!l|r)|k|c(?!i|e|y|h));` so that `$1` captures the beginning of the line or a white space (to signify the beginning of a word) until the next white space before the g, k, or c (the end of the word). Perhaps this is a parentheses problem, but I'm not sure how to keep the grouping I have while also specifying where I want `$1` to capture.

Comment: Well done on the What Have You Tried front, but for more clarity: can you add a few To match and To Not match words?

Comment: Yes, sorry! Here's some nonsense words. Match: bog go, clock gun, hog kite. No match: talking go, ark glue, bark grab.

Comment: Your conditions are pretty complex and seem kind of arbitrary. Is this for homework (perfectly fine if it is) or are you trying to solve a real-world problem? If it's a real-world problem, I'm curious what it is. Natural language processing or something like that?

Comment: I'm interested in word final velars before other stop consonants - this regex is the "control" case of velars preceding velars. I want to compare that to velars preceding coronas and labials (and more specifically, look for cases of assimilation within these two). The corpus I'm working with is not transcribed phonetically, so I'm working with the orthography. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: This is a really good example of why "single magic regex"  is a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `/(\S*(((?<!n)g)|(?<!r)k))\s(g(?!l|r)|k|c(?!i|e|y|h))/`?

EDIT: Looking at it, it could use some clean up :D

```
/(\S*([^n]g|[^r]k))\s(g[^lr]|k|c[^ieyh])/
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. I am new to perl and regexes so I often suspect I have needless things in my code, so thank you for helping me clean it up!